# View onclick data via Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, onclick

I want to pull the `onclick` information from an `a` tag. I know how to do this normally and I've confirmed it works via the console. However, it returns `null` when attempted through an extension. Is this possible via an extension and if so: what strange method must be employed?

Example:

On the page: `<a href="#" onclick="something(stuff,otherstuff)">text</a>`

I'd like to be able to grab that `something(stuff,otherstuff)`.

However, pure JS didn't work: `String(document.getElementsByTagName("a")[10].onclick)`

And neither did jQuery: `String($(".tableclass").find("tbody").find("a")[10].onclick)`

Both of the above working when entered into the console.

Comment: You know Google dev tools has Event Listeners tab, there are also extensions for getting jQuery bound elements :D

Comment: @AdamAzad Well what I'm trying to do is dynamically read that data and modify the anchor tag. So it's not that I'm trying to look at it; I'm trying to manipulate it. And it's not just one, but dozens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can never read the `onclick` property that was set by a page because extension code runs in an [isolated scope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laLudeUmXHM).

Secondly, even if the code was not isolated, the `onclick` property of `<a onclick="foo"></a>` may not have the value `foo` you are expecting. That is because a property is not the same thing as an HTML attribute.

Therefore, if you want to access the string value of an `onclick` attribute you can and *should* use `linkElement.getAttribute('onclick');` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean, that you want to change a href of the link? You can do it like this:

html:

```
<a href='foo' class='link-to-swap'>link</a>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.link-to-swap').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      var grabbedData = $(this).attr('data-id')
        $(this).attr('href',grabbedData)
      return false
  })
})
```

here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cp6x9pf5/1/

Comment: I want to take the onclick's data, re-arrange it into a url, then put that newly formed url into the href.

Comment: Updated the fiddle. Now you can grab the data tag from any link you want, and use it as you wish to update the link href.

Comment: It isn't an anchor I'm making; it doesn't possess any data attributes. It only has an onclick.